# How I can create search filter bar using data from json file?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

how to create a search bar filter by price,name that will filter my cars.json file and show cars on the page
I have a car.json file and I want to create functions using maybe fetch that will pick a list of cars and filter it and show the result

my cars.json

```
 "car": [],
  "cars": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Audi ",
     
      "price": 17000000,
  
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "bmw",
      "price": 24000000,

    },
    { .....
```

and my cars.js

```
export function Cars() {

    const section = document.createElement('section');
  
    section.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Filter" name="search">
            <button type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

return section
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by adding the filter method over json object, also I have taken the search text static that you can modify and check for name and price both.
And you can pass the input value which you get,

```
const txt =
    '{"cars": [{"id": "1","name": "Audi ","price": "17000000"},{  "id": "2",  "name": "bmw",  "price": "24000000"}]}';

  const response = JSON.parse(txt);

  const inputText = "2400";
  const sData = response.cars.filter((r) => {
    return (
      r.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
      r.price.includes(inputText)
    );
  });

  console.log(sData);
```